# Android in app purchase - get (in)active status

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm using Androids inAppPurchase system. Since the app is supposed to have different offers, I created two SKUs

- one for original prices and
- one for offers.

The plan was to show the offer unless I deactivate it and then show the  original SKU (price, description,...) . 
The problem is, I assumed an inactive item would be null (or marked somehow) but I still get both items and the SkuDetails don't have any attribute telling it's status.

Only once I start the purchase I get an error message from Google

```
"Error fetching information from the server [DF-AA-20]"
```

which I interpret as "the item is deactivated".

**How can I get the state of a SKU before I try selling it to the user?**